# Как определить по какому элементу был клик?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть много элементов списка с одним и тем же `id='report-started'`. При нажатии на который я в js должен получить его `data-progress`.
Как разграничить эти элементы списка и узнать на какой я нажал?

Я понимаю, что можно каждому `id='report-started'` добавить уникальное значение типа `id='report-started-123'` и `id='report-started-234'` и т.д., но не понимаю как тогда определять по какому именно элементу был клик?

В примере клик срабатывает только на первом элементе.
Спасибо.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#report-started').on('click', function() {
    var progress = $(this).attr('data-progress');
    console.log(progress);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-progress="[1, 2]" id="report-started">
    Открыть
  </li>
  
  <li data-progress="[3, 4]" id="report-started">
    Открыть
  </li>
  
  <li data-progress="[5, 6]" id="report-started">
    Открыть
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: на странице не может быть несколько элементов с одинаковым id

Comment: @Дмытрык, ну не то чтобы совсем не может :-)

Comment: Хорошо, не может) но как определить на стороне js по какому именно элементу был клик? Нужно получить дата-атрибут нажатого элемента.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо `id` в данном случае нужно использовать `class`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.report-started').on('click', function() {
    var progress = $(this).attr('data-progress');
    console.log(progress);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-progress="[1, 2]" class="report-started">
    Открыть
  </li>

  <li data-progress="[3, 4]" class="report-started">
    Открыть
  </li>

  <li data-progress="[5, 6]" class="report-started">
    Открыть
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Однако если очень хочется использовать именно одинаковые `id` несмотря на то, что это может привести к другим проблемам, можно немного изменить селектор:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li#report-started').on('click', function() {
    var progress = $(this).attr('data-progress');
    console.log(progress);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-progress="[1, 2]" id="report-started">
    Открыть
  </li>

  <li data-progress="[3, 4]" id="report-started">
    Открыть
  </li>

  <li data-progress="[5, 6]" id="report-started">
    Открыть
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо, честно говоря не думал что `id` и `class` в этом случае будут различаться. Думал они одинаково будут реагировать только на первый элемент.

Comment: @evans, класс как раз и предназначен для множественного использования

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log('target', e.target);
  console.log('currentTarget', e.currentTarget);
  console.log('evt', e);
  message.innerHTML = e.target.tagName;
});
```

Можешь почитать про всплытие событий, чтоб такие темы были понятнее.

Далее, определив таргет нажатия, можно просто через css селектор взять родителя, или чайлда.